# Why Are Emails Sent via Apex Code Bouncing for Non-System Admin Users Despite Successful Send Status?

Tags: apex

I'm using Apex code to send emails, and while **Messaging.SendMailResult** indicates success and the email appears in the related task view as sent, it changes to a bounced status 1-2 minutes later. However, when I send the same email as a System Administrator, there are no issues, but emails bounce when sent by other personas. The Deliverability setting is configured to allow All Emails. I'm seeking advice on why this might be happening and how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emails in Salesforce aren't immediately sent, but rather placed into a queue for later delivery. Messaging.SendMailResult's "success" simply means that the emails were placed into this queue for delivery. To resolve the issue, you'll need to look at the email logs. In Setup, go to Environments | Logs | Email Log Files, and then request a new log for one of the test users you're sending as. In a few moments, you should get an email telling you the results are ready. From there, you'll see what the remote email server's response is, and that will tell you how to fix the problem.